# ASP.NET - Serilog - Multiple sinks each one for a different use

Tags: asp.net, .net, logging, serilog

I want to use Serilog for logging because I worked with it and it fits my needs.

The difference in this case is that I need to log different modules and I would like each module to be logged in a different folder and even maybe in a different sink.

I am not talking about using several sinks, but I talk about doing something like this:

```
Serilog.Log(LogInstance1,"Log for module 1") // Logs in a rolling text file in folder X 10 files of 1MB each
Serilog.Log(LogInstance2,"Log for module 2") // Logs i na text file that doesn't delete old entries
```

Does anyone know if this is possible to achieve with Serilog?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make multiple separate `ILogger` instances, each with their own configuration and set of sinks etc.; each pipeline operates completely separately with no shared state of any kind.

```
var logger1 = new LoggerConfiguration().
    .WriteTo.File(...10...)
    .CreateLogger();

var logger2 = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.File(...)
    .CreateLogger();

logger1.Information("Log for Module 1");
logger2.Information("Log for Module 2");
```

Comment: Great! That was what I was looking for. could you up vote my question if you find it a good one?

Comment: how to inject logger1 or logger2 (or both) using DI according to the needs?

Comment: @kevinob use the named instance mechanism your DI container provides to tag the instances (that's a separate question though, and obviously it depends on the container you are using). However, in general for apps, I'd suggest that a static `Serilog.ILogger` instance that's established on startup is generally a reasonable way to go