# How can split log data into file and database within the same controller class in asp.net core, using Serilog?

Tags: asp.net-core, serilog

I am trying Serilog for my logging requirements with asp.net core web application.
I am new to both of these frameworks.
I really want to understand how to configure the logger so that I can log *separate data to both file and database sinks simultaneously (say from within the same controller class).
I tried researching on the internet, since I read Serilog has a good documentation, but I failed to find the exact configuration I need for my requirement.

With someone's suggestion on another stackoverflow question related to multiple sinks [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50370374/asp-net-serilog-multiple-sinks-each-one-for-a-different-use).

I tried to do the following:

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
 {
        var logger1 = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .WriteTo.File("Logs\\system_.log", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
                .CreateLogger();

        var logger2 = new LoggerConfiguration()
           .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(connectionString,
            sinkOptions: new MSSqlServerSinkOptions { TableName = "logs" })
               .CreateLogger();

        logger1.Information("hello to file");
        logger2.Information("hello to database"); 

        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}

public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            })
            .UseSerilog();
```

This partially works, I was able to see distinct logs in log file and database(Sql server) respectively, but now I do not know how to use these two configurations from inside a controller class.

As the following code from my controller class does not log anything in any of the sinks

```
 public class UserController : ControllerBase
{        
    private ILogger<UserController> _logger;

    public UserController(ILogger<UserController> logger)
    {           
        _logger = logger;
        _logger.LogInformation("Writing to log file with INFORMATION severity level.");            
        _logger.LogWarning("Writing to log file with WARNING severity level.");
        _logger.LogError("Writing to log file with ERROR severity level.");
        
    }
```

Any suggestions would be really helpful, thanks in advance.

Comment: Dependency injection, Ilogger and Serilog, in startup ConfigureServices:  services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder =>
            {
                loggingBuilder.AddSerilog();
            });

Comment: Okay I forgot to add that piece of code, but I have already added .UseSerilog() to CreateHostBuilder(), I do not know if this is what you mean.

Comment: it's the same thing, I don't get you what are the needs then, what is not working

Answer (score 0):

Bit overdue but for the devs that search for the same thing as I did.
You can add an extra line 'WriteTo' in your config. An example:

```
 string conn = config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? string.Empty;

 var sinkOpts = new MSSqlServerSinkOptions();
 sinkOpts.TableName = "Logging";
 sinkOpts.AutoCreateSqlTable = true;

 builder.Host.UseSerilog((ctx, lc) => lc
                 .MinimumLevel.Fatal()
                 .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Fatal)
                 .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                 .WriteTo.File(Path.Combine(logPath, "log.txt"),
                         outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} {Level:u15}   Class: {SourceContext:l, 50}{NewLine}          {Message:lj}{NewLine}          {Exception}",
                         rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Month, fileSizeLimitBytes: 10000000)
                 .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(
                         connectionString: conn,
                         sinkOptions: sinkOpts
                         ));
```

You have to add the sinks for MSSQL and file to make this work. Conn cannot be empty as it is checked in the other part of the code. The logPath is also set higher in the code.